# Java is open-source, so what?

Tags: java, .net, open-source

I always hear that Java being open-source is a big benefit, but I fail to see how Java being open-source should draw me to use it as opposed to .NET which is closed-source.  [This website](http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/faq.jsp) has some Q&A sections (*What is the significance of these developments to the industry?* in particular) that give a little info, but is being free the only (or the biggest) advantage to Java being open-source?

Since I am a beginner, have any of you pros noticed any major difference since the change was made?

EDIT:

Please disregard the .NET part of this question, I was simply using it as a comparison.  **What I really care about is knowing what benefit becoming open-source has been to Java.**

Comment: I'm tempted to flag as Subjective and Argumentative, but prepared to give it the benefit of the doubt, as it could lead to some interesting answers. What do others think?

Comment: You probably should make this question community wiki, as it has no definite answer. Just click edit and mark the checkbox below the question text.

Comment: @johnc: I voted to close. Mono kinda makes the question moot, so I don't think anything useful can come out of it... Let's see.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative, I really want to know. I just do not see how being open-source in the context of a development framework is an advantage or disadvantage (other than the fact that the software tools for developing in Java are for the most part free). Some people below said it is not fair to call .NET closed-source, but I have been taught differently. If I have been taught wrong could someone enlighten me with some specific literature?  Additionally, I do not see how Mono can count, as it is not officially supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @typoknig I'm in no way attempting to paint you as a troll. Voting to close is a mechanism to keep the available questions as objective as possible to avoid SO becoming a 'conversation' site. For the record, I have not voted to close this question.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes True. However, I think any [insert java vs .NET question] is probably always going to be subjective (although I have many heartfelt reasons why I crossed the floor to .NET) and argumentative, hence the comment.

Comment: I should have just left the .NET out of it, I was just using it as a comparison.  I really just want to know what benefit open-source is to Java.

Comment: @johnc: It probably depends a lot on how the question is asked. I think you can ask objective questions, if you are specific and careful no to tread in what I call "ideological" matters. Anyway, I actually learned something with this question, so I wish I could undo my vote. Are you listening Jeff? @typoknig: yeah, that would have given you more to-the-point answers like Thilo's.

Comment: @typoknig: a huge benefit is that Java is basically the biggest language success story of these last 20 years or so and is now widely known and used... The *last* thing you'd have wanted was Sun to go bankrupt or be bought for a few pennies by a company like MS that would have killed Java. Now that it is open source, the biggest language success story of these last 20 years is here to stay for good. The Java legacy is going to dwarf COBOL thanks, in part, to Java now being open-sourced :)  Nobody can buy it and kill it anymore.  That's the big benefit.  No vendor lock-in.  No disappearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are a mainstream user, there is probably no immediate benefit for you.

However, the open-source base of Java makes it easier for people to adapt it to more niche requirements that the closed-source vendor sees no need to support. Smaller vendors (or open source projects) can come up with solutions to these special needs.

For example, Java runs on a great variety of platforms and operating systems, most of them supported by companies other than Sun (granted, that was the case even before it was open source).

> have any of you pros noticed any major difference since the change was made

I like the fact that Linux distributions now include the "official" Sun JVM and JDK, rather than making you install it separately or use the "mostly-compatible" alternative implementation that was provided.

Comment: "I like the fact that Linux distributions now include the "official" Sun JVM and JDK, rather than making you install it separately or use the "mostly-compatible" alternative implementation that was provided." Thank you, this is the kind of info I am looking for. Something about Java being open-source that has actually been a benefit to the platform. Do you have a link to any literature on this subject?

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely fair to say .NET is closed source - Microsoft's .NET runtime and development tools are closed-source.

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an open-source implementation of many things in the .NET world - the CLR and C# being the biggest.

Comment: .NET is a Microsoft product though, Mono is not.  That is like calling a Ford (closed-source) a Chevy (open-source) just because you change the emblem.

Comment: @mmsmatt: sure, but you never know for how long it's going to stay 'open'. Miguel de Icaza, the biggest .Net 'believer' has very bad thing to say about this SNAFU recently: http://www.itwire.com/opinion-and-analysis/open-sauce/37880-microsoft-has-shot-net-ecosystem-in-foot-de-icaza   I'd be very cautious when it comes to trusting a company that has consistently played dirty and that has been ruled to have abused its monopoly to conserve and extend its monopoly (that's the final verdict) to provide something 'open' and to play nice.  Even de Icaza realizes this now.  Took him years that said ;)

Answer (score 3):

The primary implementation of .NET is closed source, though there are competing open-source implementations.

The primary implementation of JVM is open source, though there are competing closed-source implementations.

The standard for Java remains entirely under control of Sun (Oracle). Others are allowed to provide input, but final decisions are up to Sun.

The standard for CLR is entirely under control of the ECMA and ISO. Microsoft is allowed to provide input, but the final decision is up to the standards bodies. If Microsoft *did* ignore their decision, it's open to question whether the standard would remain relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The improvements to OpenJDK since it was open-sourced have been immeasurable, here is just a few:

- The [Zero](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/zero/) project, contributed by Redhat, has ported Hotspot to many new platforms like PowerPC (32 and 64 bit), IA-64, ARM and zSeries, and made future ports to other platforms much easier. The Shark subproject has also given it better performance on some of those platforms
- The OpenJDK has been ported to new operating systems, such as [Haiku](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/haiku-port/) and [BSD](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/bsd-port/)
- [Many bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net) have been reported and fixed by individuals and companies
- [Apple](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/11/12openjdk.html) has joined the OpenJDK project and a MacOS port is in the pipeline
- So has IBM
- Various innovative projects, such as [IcedRobot](http://www.fosdem.org/2011/schedule/event/icedrobot) have become possible
- OpenJDK jtreg tests are now available to other Java implementations

Some of the direct benefits to the average Java programmer are:

- You can investigate and fix bugs in the JDK source code
- You can build custom versions of the OpenJDK (eg. strip it down to make it smaller)
- You don't need to pay license fees to ship OpenJDK on embedded devices

Answer (score 1):

Java and .Net are both standards for which anyone can write an open-source implementation. .Net 3.0 just happens to have no complete open-source implementations.

Regardless of openness, the difference for you (and the reason many people choose Java at all) is portability. There are far more implementations of Java, and most are closed.

Java can create apps for cell phones. Java can create web apps. Java runs on Mac. Not .Net.

Sun is just advertising the simplification and standardization which a common open-source core may provide. But if you look closely at the page you linked, you'll see that it's using the future tense.

Comment: Isn't Mono open-source, not to mention on a different OS besides Windows?

Comment: "The implementation of Java which you or your users actually use isn't necessarily open-source. " Good point. The Mac JVM certainly is not (even though it is supposedly mostly based on Sun's code)

Comment: @Potatocorn: Even the portability argument is getting moot. Several Gnome apps use Mono now. How many Java applications do you see included in Linux distributions?

Comment: -1 for .net having only one platform.

Comment: @Kibibu: I edited that out before you downvoted me.

Comment: @Martinho: How many .net apps have you seen for cellphones?

Comment: Mono is a *complete* implementation of .NET 2.0 (source: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility).

Comment: @Potatocorn: ok, removed

Answer (score 1):

Opening up the JVM source helps in porting it to other architectures such as ARM for embedded use.

Answer (score 0):

More choices. Flexibility. Java Community Process. I think mainly lower cost of ownership - Eclipse+ApacheServer+Linux - are all free.